# XPages - Create Word Documents with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages, lotus-notes

I'm trying to use Apache POI within XPages to create a Word document. I have a button which executes some SSJS to call a method from a Java class. However, as soon as the Java code tries to instantiate a new object, an error occurs. Here is my code:

SSJS:

```
importPackage(TESTPackage);
var jce:WordReferenceTest = new WordReferenceTest();
jce.newWordDoc();
```

Java:

```
package TESTPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReferenceTest {

public void newWordDoc() {

    try {   

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

I have IBM Notes 9.0 and have imported all the Apache POI JAR files as JARS directly into my database.
The error message I get is 
Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I added the error message above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OpenNTF there is OpenNTF Essentials. It contains everything that you need to handle word documents. Try to use that. You might run foul of [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644523/apache-poi-generated-word-document-works-but-invokes-a-security-warning?rq=1) or logging.

Reuse what is there already.

Comment: Thanks, the POI for XPages works really well. However it does require installing some files on the server and I would like to also be able to present customers with an option which does not involve installing third party files.

Comment: Apache POI itself is 3rd party already. So? The simple approach is to package your offering into an update site. Then: replicate NSF to server, change ini parameter, restart http, done.